# Does'nt configMap referencing in POD requires ServiceAccount?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, configmap

Curious as to how configMaps can be referenced in PODs without appropriate serviceAccount and asscoiated RBAC rules ?

**Sample POD Yaml mounting configMap**

```
    - mountPath: /kubernetes-vault
      name: kubernetes-vault

       .................
       .................

          volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: vault-token
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: kubernetes-vault
    name: kubernetes-vault
```

But the `associated ServiceAccount and it's corresponding RBAC ( Role and RoleBinding )` does'nt have any rules specifying access rules for this `configMap (kubernetes-vault)`

**Role & Rule for the POD**

```
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - services
  - pods
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

**Couple of Qs**

- does'nt access to configMap required appropriate ServiceAccount with access rules specified specifically for configMap access ?
- if yest which rule mentioned above governs configMap Access
- if not , what objects are governed by RBAC rules ?

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't access to configMap required appropriate ServiceAccount with access rules specified specifically for configMap access ?

It will when a `ServiceAccount` is performing that action, yes, but `volumes:` are performed by a mixture of `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller`, and the calling credential that interacts with the apiserver. By the time the Pod's volumes mount, all those security checks are a done deal -- one can verify that behavior by running any Pod and suppressing its `ServiceAccount` and observe that the volume mounts still take place

If one has objects which should only be accessed by a limited set of users, that should happen at the Role level to prevent the users from scheduling Pods that touch the sensitive items.

> if not , what objects are governed by RBAC rules ?

As far as I know, *everything* is governed by RBAC rules, and even if they aren't to your satisfaction, the system offers [Validating Admission Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook) which allow **extremely** fine-grained access rules

Comment: thanks @mdaniel , i'am specifically interested on if RBAC rules govern configMap access , have updated the question with currenlty effective **Rules** , please advice.